# Call JsonResult by string name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller that has 50+ private functions that return JsonResult type.  I'm trying to create a generic JsonResult that accepts a name string that corresponds to one of the 50+ private JsonResult functions.

I want to do something like this:

```
    public JsonResult View(Guid id, string funcName)
    {           
        return RedirectToAction(funcName, "myController", new { id = id});
    }
```

but this won't work because "RedirectToAction" returns an ActionResult, not a JsonResult.
Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Side note: "50+ private functions" - and the fact that actions must be public methods make your sample somewhat strange.

Comment: "I have a controller that has 50+ private functions " That's something you need to fix. Too many methods in one class will be a pain to maintain. Try to refactor those methods if you can. Maybe you need more then one controller in the project? Or maybe put those methods in separate helpers classes?

Comment: Sounds like you have a major structural code issue there.

Comment: Do you have custom `RedirectToAction` or use regular one [Controller.RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) that returns 302 redirect result which clearly is not `JsonResult` ?

Comment: Please don't get hung up on the "50+ functions" issue since it's just an EXAMPLE.  The functions are actually in a ViewModel and can return a number of values depending on what the json call needs.  So, going back to the REAL QUESTION - is there a way to dynamically return a JsonResult function by it's string name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+reflection+call+method+name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
public ActionResult View(Guid id, string funcName)
{           
    return (ActionResult)this.GetType().GetMethod(funcName).Invoke(this, new object[]{id});
}
```

As mentioned in comments. If its private method you will need to add binding flags:

```
return (ActionResult)this.GetType().GetMethod(funcName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(this, new object[]{id});
```

Comment: +1. Reflection is indeed the only way to call private function by name (may need to add flags to find private method). `RedirectToAction` will not help since `private` methods can't be actions.

Answer (score 0):

`JsonResult` inherits from `ActionResult`. You can just have your View action return it.

```
public ActionResult View(Guid id, string funcName)
{           
    return RedirectToAction(funcName, "myController", new { id = id});
}
```

If your `RedirectToAction` line returns a `JsonResult`, it will handle it appropriately. MVC does not care.

Comment: Hmm, hadn't tried this. I thought if I returned Json in an ActionResult, the headers would be different and it would mess up my jquery ajax code. I'll try it right now.

Comment: @Losbear - note that main part of this answer is "*your* RedirectToAction line returns a JsonResult", because framework one returns redirect.